# NodeJS MYSQL delete query

Tags: mysql, node.js, delete-row

I am trying to delete a row in MYSQL table from NodeJS route. The query works fine by itself when i run it in MySQL Workbench. When executed from Node the row is not deleted. I don't get any error messages on either server or client side. Here is the code:

```
router.post('/bid_delete', async (req, res) => {
 let bid_no = req.body['bid_no']
 let qrBids= "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; DELETE FROM bids_hdr WHERE 
 bid_gen_id ='" + bid_no + "';"  
 await pool.query( qrBids, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    res.send(err)
  } else {
    res.json({success : true})
  }  
 });  
})
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: You can't execute multiple queries in a single call to `pool.query()`. Execute them sequentially.

Comment: You should also use placeholders in the query rather than concatenating strings, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @Barmar. Thank You very much. Can you explain briefly use of placeholders with example if possible.

Comment: Do you really have a newline in the `qrBids` string? JavaScript doesn't allow newlines in string literals (you can use them in template literals, but not single-quoted or double-quoted literals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDTES = 0;` in a separate query.

And use a placeholder instead of concatenation to substitute a variable into the query.

```
router.post('/bid_delete', async (req, res) => {
 let bid_no = req.body['bid_no']
 let qrBids= "DELETE FROM bids_hdr WHERE bid_gen_id = ?"  
 await pool.query( "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0");
 await pool.query( qrBids, [bid_no], (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    res.send(err)
  } else {
    res.json({success : true})
  }  
 });  
})
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass param as is eg.

```
let qrBids= "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; DELETE FROM bids_hdr WHERE bid_gen_id = '1';"
```

Comment: The parameter comes from a variable, he can't hard-code it like this.